# Microsoft Edge not executing Javascript

Tags: javascript, https, microsoft-edge

It came to my attention today that Microsoft Edge (version 38.14393.0.0) does not execute the Javascript on my site. This is a problem for my users. Unfortunately, when I open the developer console (F12) to look for errors, and reload the page, Javascript is executed without problems, and continues to work after that even when closing the dev. console. This might indicate that the external Javascript file is not loaded initially, and for some reason, the dev. console is less strict, and once the file is in the cache, it works. The static files including Javascript are on a different domain (to make sure no cookies are sent and the files can be properly cached), so that might be an issue, however the style sheet from that same domain is loaded without problems. Everything is https and has valid certificates. I am sending no Content-Security-Policy headers at the moment.

Everything works correctly in Internet Explorer. Any ideas what is making Edge stumble?

Comment: Can you show us how you implement your javascript in your page ?

Comment: I am not sure if posting a link is frowned upon, but it is probably best if people can check it out themselves: [buchhaltung-muehelos.de](https://secure.buchhaltung-muehelos.de). I basically include a few external Javascript files at the bottom of the page, plus I have some inline JS right below that.

Answer (score 0):

Put you javascript import in the head tag, jquery had to be loaded before your script is executed.

```
   ...
   <script type="text/javascript" src="https://static.buchhaltung-muehelos.com/_files/cache/f63cabe51021196712a38fc1ca89d040.js"></script>
</head>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not help. It would also not explain why it did work in all other browsers. See my other comment.

Answer (score 0):

After intensive search and experimenting I finally found the culprit: it was the Google Analytics code. It appears that after the latest update of "ga.js" by Google, it stopped working in Edge. It is likely that this had something to do with my particular method of implementing the GA tags (since otherwise this problem would probably be much more widespread), but my solution now was that I switched to Google Universal Analytics tags (analytics.js) and implemented the tracking exactly as recommended by Google, and now Edge no longer chokes on my Javascript.